# libgdx keyDown distinguishing a long and short press

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way to handle a keydown that is just one click versus a keydown that is a long press in libgdx? Does it have anything to do with a gesture detector?
**to clarify, my question is about keyboard events, not touch and mouse events**

Comment: Well, you need to define what is a "long press"? Is it a second? Or even longer? A possible way to distinguish them would be to store current time on key down and calculate a delta in the keyUp method. If this delta is bigger then the delta needed for a "long press", it is a long press. Gesture detection instead is about inputs on touchscreen, as much as i know. It is made to detect f.e. slides etc.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GestureDetector` is used for touch and mouse events only.
To distinguish between short and long key-presses you might implement your own `InputProcessor`, which stores the currentTime in a variable (`keyDownTime`?) in the `keyDown` method and calculates the `delta` between the `keyDownTime` and the currentTime.
If the calculated `delta` is bigger then the delta needed to be a "long press", then the key-evnet was a long press, else it was a short press.
If your `InputProcessor` should be able to detect long and short presses for multiple keys, then you might store an `IntMap<int, long>`, where the `int key` is the `keyCode` and the `long value` is the `keyDownTime`.
Use the `keyCode` in the `keyDown` to `put` the `keyDownTime` and in the `keyUp` to `get` the `keyDownTime`, then calculate the `delta` and you know, if it is a long press or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way and yes, it's done via the [Gesture-detector](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gesture-detection). You can set what you define as a "long press" when creating the object in the [constructor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html#GestureDetector-float-float-float-float-com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.GestureListener-) (the `longPressDuration` argument). E.g.,

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(20, 0.4f, 1.1f, 0.15f, new MyGestureListener()));
```

Will set a new `GestureDetector` as the input processor with a "long press" defined as any press longer than 1.1 seconds (third argument). Inside `MyGestureListener` you'll define what you want to happen when the long press event occurs by overriding the `longPress` method.

Comment: But isn't that about touchInput? The user instead wants to detect long key-presses. Does the `GestureDetector` has some method for that to?

Comment: @Springrbua you are correct, `GestureDetector` is for touch /mouse events. I thought the OP asked about mouse inputs because he used the term "one click", which sounds like a mouse event.

Comment: I meant keyboard events, not touch and mouse events, sorry for the confusion.